# Tailwind css hover not changing text color

Tags: css, colors, hover, tailwind-css

I am completely new to this tailwindcss and I have been stuck at this problem for the entire day. I am so frustrated. Here is my code

```
<button className="bg-yellow-500 px-4 py-2 hover:text-black text-white">
        Some Text Here
 </button>
```

What I want to achieve is to change the text color when the button is hovered, current text color is white and I want it to change to black. It didn't work. When I use chrome inspect tool, I found that the text color white has !important which I don't know how it happened. I didn't define it, don't even know how to. What's even worst is that I can change the text color to any color when it's hovered if it's original color is not white. I can have another color initially other than white and change it to whatever color I like.
As you can see, its very simple. I can do it with pure css in like 10 s, no need to for an entire day.
Please, help me out here.

Here is the tailwind.config file if it's necessay,

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    boxShadow: {
      sm: "0 1px 5px #65656599",
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        body: ["Poppins"],
      },
      colors: {
        black: {
          hakkei: "#1a1a1a",
          DEFAULT: "#000",
        },
        current: "currentColor",
        gray: colors.blueGray,
        indigo: colors.indigo,
        red: colors.rose,
        yellow: colors.amber,
        blue: colors.blue,
        black: "#333",
        white: "#fff",
        aqua: {
          DEFAULT: "#99ced3",
          dark: "#8abbbf",
        },
        navy: {
          light: "#99ced3",
          DEFAULT: "#2f415d",
          dark: "#1d2a3d",
          sky: "#00afffc2",
        },
        purple: colors.purple,
      },
      borderRadius: {
        "5xl": "5rem",
        "10xl": "10rem",
        "20xl": "50%",
      },
      height: {
        120: "32rem",
        150: "40rem",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    textColor: ["responsive", "hover", "focus", "group-hover"],
  },

  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss",
    //require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    "@tailwindcss-neumorphism",
  ],
};
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I tested your code in the `Tailwind Play` but your goal was work. please check this link and comment out more detailed infomation with your current code. :) https://play.tailwindcss.com/dHgStQO7DA

Comment: It might be because the colors you manually added replace existing colors. Add new colors inside extends{}

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `black` twice. If you want the default value for black to be `#333` then just add that value like the following:

```js
      colors: {
        black: {
          hakkei: "#1a1a1a",
          DEFAULT: "#333", // it was #000 before
        },
```

and remove the other line between blue and white.